# Do abbreviated names need a period after them if they have a comma after?

Tags: punctuation

I learned that when abbreviating a word, such as "*tomorrow*" as "*tom.,*" we should place a period right after it. But what about when it's a name? For example, which sentence would be correct? (The abbreviated name is "*Gavin.*")

With the period:

> "*Gav., what are you doing this Saturday?*"

Without the period:

> "*Gav, what are you doing this Saturday?*"

Do abbreviate names need a period after them?

Comment: An interesting thought! Certainly the consensus is not to use a period for shortened names, but I don't have a definitive reason why. Perhaps "Gav" is treated as a nickname rather than an abbreviation, and I can't see a period being added to "Tommy" for example.

Comment: The short answer is "nobody ever does that, so you shouldn't either". I'll leave more formal justifications to others.

Comment: I don't think that a shortened form of a name counts as an abbreviation.

Comment: '... we should place a period right after it' is not a binding rule, as has been discussed here before. It may be the more favoured style, and is an option I choose when disambiguation is necessary, but is probably losing favour. And certainly diminutives (such as Gav) would rarely if ever have a period tacked on.

Comment: In many (but not all) instances of word abbreviation, the word would be pronounced in full even when written as an abbreviation. For example, you would write "etc." but say "et cetera"; on the other hand, if you write "e.g." you might say "E G" or "for example".  In the case of an abbreviated name / nickname, you would usually say it as written.

Comment: It is possible that there are circumstances you might, or at least where that used to be the convention. I'm thinking of forms and registers where space is limited and standard abbreviations are used, such as 'Arch' plus a superscript 'd' for Archibald or 'Geo' for Geoffrey. Such as  in this example from the National Records of Scotland. https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/files//images/alma-street-govan-ref-1881-646-01-19-p7.jpg But that use is quite different from someone being *called* 'Gav' in that they would not be expected to be pronounced as written.

Comment: No, you don't need a period after the "short name" (not an "abbreviated" name).

Comment: A "shortened name" is generally a "nickname", and does not take a period after.  (Consider, among other things, that many such names -- Joe, Bill, Hank, Mike, etc -- are not simple truncations of the full name.)  The exception would be in something like a genealogy document, where common names like "George" are abbreviated for compactness.  In your "Gav" example you are quoting speech, and "Gav" is clearly intended to be spoken as a nickname.

Comment: Reminds me of **Judi Dench**, who played the character of the Head of Secret Intelligence Service in Bond movies, as *Olivia Mansfield* aka *Emma*, known by the initial "**M**"(without a period).

Answer (score 2):

Abbreviated names often do have periods in them, as in "Jos. A. Bank." This case is different from the one in the OP's example, which as some commenters have observed is probably a nickname rather than an abbreviation.

The Wiktionary list of [Abbreviations for English Names](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Abbreviations_for_English_given_names) claims that a period is left off if the abbreviation ends with the last letter of the name (as in "Thos" for Thomas). But surely this nuance depends on what style guide you are using.

Comment: I've always understood that omission of the period if the last letter of the original word is present in the abbreviation applies to *all* abbreviations - not merely to names (except that the period should still be included if the abbreviated form were ambiguous, *e.g.* if the abbreviation could be a word in its own right).